# Prometheus counter inside async call

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, counter, prometheus

I'm working with Prometheus Histograms and Counters and openAPI. What I'm looking somehow make the counter work : Creates a record with exact status and count them. When I'm getting 200, everything works out, but when I get any error code, I'm not getting anything into STATUS_COUNTER. I assumed it was caused by **`raise_for_status`** but I wasn't able to do it even with raising after the record. What am I doing wrong? I heard I could be able to do it with hooks but I don't have any experience with it. Let me know if you know! Thanks a lot : )

tried it with if and calling raise_for_status later:

```
from prometheus_client import Histogram, Counter


    with HIST.labels(model_id, version_id).time():

        async with client_session.post(
            settings.url,
            json=data,
            allow_redirects=False,
        ) as response:
            print(response.status)
            STATUS_COUNTER.labels(response.status).inc(1)
            if not response.status == 200:
                response.raise_for_status()

            return await response.json()
```

original state:

```
from prometheus_client import Histogram, Counter

    with HIST.labels(model_id, version_id).time():
        async with client_session.post(
            settings.URL,
            json=data,
            allow_redirects=False,
            raise_for_status=True,
        ) as response:
            STATUS_COUNTER.labels(response.status).inc(1)
            return await response.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with Python async but this is an interesting question.

I think perhaps you're missing a `try ... expect ...` around the `async client_sessions.post(...) ...` in order to catch failures with (in my case) the `get`.

The following works for me:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json
import time

from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Counter

c = Counter("requests_total", "Total count of requests", ["code"])


async def get_url(client, url):
    try:
        async with client.get(url) as response:
            c.labels(code=response.status).inc(1)
            resp = await response.read()
            return resp
    # You want something more specific than Exception
    # And you want to handle it
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: {e}".format(e=e))


async def get(code):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as client:
        url = "https://httpstat.us/{code}".format(code=code)
        await get_url(client, url)

        print("Done: {code}".format(code=code))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_http_server(8080)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    while (True):
        futures = [
            get(code) for code in {
                200: 1,
                202: 2,
                204: 3,
                301: 4,
                400: 5,
                401: 6,
                410: 7,
                500: 8,
            }
        ]
        result = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*futures))
        time.sleep(10)
```

And curl'ing `http://localhost:8080/metrics` yields:

```
# HELP requests_total Total count of requests
# TYPE requests_total counter
requests_total{code="202"} 2.0
requests_total{code="500"} 2.0
requests_total{code="400"} 2.0
requests_total{code="200"} 4.0
requests_total{code="410"} 2.0
requests_total{code="204"} 2.0
requests_total{code="401"} 2.0
# HELP requests_created Total count of requests
# TYPE requests_created gauge
requests_created{code="202"} 1.6221402488908508e+09
requests_created{code="500"} 1.6221402488980236e+09
requests_created{code="400"} 1.6221402488994935e+09
requests_created{code="200"} 1.6221402489686863e+09
requests_created{code="410"} 1.6221402490579622e+09
requests_created{code="204"} 1.6221402493150167e+09
requests_created{code="401"} 1.622140249339906e+09
```

> **NOTE** I'm unsure why the client produces `requests_created`